# Need ThunderBird type App for Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, software-recommendation

Want an App to have multiple email accounts like Thunderbird, for UbuntuTouch 16.04. Not Outlook.

Privacy Issues with Microsoft.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion [Dekko](https://uappexplorer.com/app/dekko.dekkoproject) is a promising candidate, although it lacks push notification right now. You may give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. It says beta and work in progress, That is fine.

Comment: If you see any other Ubuntu Touch email App in the future, please drop me an email, knowyourexit@chef.net ,, thanks Paul

Comment: No Luck, Dekko was installed but would not Start. It stated to update OS. I updated and then the OS Ubuntu touch would not start up, the download was 349mb. Have on a triple boot phone, Android 5.0.1, FireFox 2.0 and Ubuntu Touch. But now I have NO touch, it will not start. Considering a factory reset. Nothing else works.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to install Thunderbird on Ubuntu-Touch. However it won't be much use unless you're running it on a tablet. Even then I find that it's awkward without a mouse.

If you do have a tablet you can install Thunderbird into the default libertine container with the following instruction:

```
libertine-container-manager install-package -d vivid -p thunderbird
```